# Which one grows faster?

Tags: asymptotics

Is the following statement true or false?

$(\log n)^{10} = O(n^{0.10})$

When trying to solve this, I thought it was false, but according to my teacher's answers, it's true.

I would like to know if there is a quick and easy way to solve exercises like this?

Comment: I have no idea how to write exponents correctly and Google's answer was wrong, apparently.

Comment: Sometimes it pays to simplify the comparison.  By definition the claim being made is that as $n$ tends to infinity (?!), the ratio of $(\log n)^{10}$ to $n^{0.1}$ is bounded.  Think about whether we can work instead with the tenth root of both numerator and denominator, showing that simplified ratio is bounded.

Comment: You'd probably like to bookmark the [Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for posting mathematical expressions and related notational matters.

Answer (score 1):

Any power of logarithm grows slower than any positive power of $n$. If you look at the limit of $\frac{\log ((\log n)^k)}{\log ( n^p)} = \frac{ k \log \log n}{p \log n} \to 0$ since $\log \log n / \log n \to 0$ for any $k,p$. So, there exists a $N$ such tat for all $n \geq N$, $(\log n)^{10} \leq n^{0.10}$ (else the limit described prior would be a constant or tending to infinity).

Comment: Using my exact example, how could I show that
$O(n^{0.10})$
grows faster? It always seems to have less growth than the other one when I try to calculate it using random numbers, but that might be the wrong way to check it.

Comment: Let $n=e^{1000}$. On the left we have $1000^{10}$, on the right $e^{100}$, which is bigger by quite a bit, since $e^{10}\gt 2^{10}\gt 1000$.  It is not hard to show that the LHS is less than the RHS past $n=e^{1000}$.  We don't need to go all the way to $e^{1000}$, but we do have to go out a very long way, which accounts for the fact that numerical experimentation did not succeed.